# Does Amazon EKS supports X509 client authentication?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I know Kubenretes supports various authentication methods like X509, bearer token, webhook token authentication.

I want to know specific to Amazon EKS if it supports X509 Client cert authentication.